# Force quit running background job

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am running background job by using add_action hook, hook starts on REST API CALL:

```
   if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'bg_job_hook' ) ) {
          wp_schedule_single_event( time(), 'bg_job_hook');
          get_headers(get_site_url());
    }

add_action( 'bg_job_hook', array( $this->$bg, 'do_background' ) );
```

it works fine, but I would to quit this job, so on another api call I add an option, and inside background job I get this option on every loop.
I see that this quit option is updated in DB, but logs from loop shows me that not. If iteration quits, and I will background job again, it will after first loop because get_option shows true..

Why during loop it is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for some reason caching works strange in WP :) 
So I resigned from using get_option, and I am doing pure SQL query to DB, and everything works fine.